# PostgreSQL 9.0 live migration/replication with native/bucardo between multiple architectures

Tags: postgresql, migration

I'm writing here because I'm in desperate need of a stable and good solution for resolving a issue we are facing.
We have an old PostgreSQL server running on RHEL 4 i386 with PostgreSQL 9.0 (postgresql-server-9.0.13-5.1.el4) with about 135 GB of raw data in the data folder. One of the big issues with this machine is that I can't install any new software and any attempts at installing yum fails so I have ruled this out of the picture. I have been able to compile a newer version of rsync on the machine which possibly brings slightly better performance but it's questionable.

I need to migrate this database to a CentOS 6 x86_64 running the same PostgreSQL versionpost but for 64 bit architecture (postgresql-server-9.0.13-5.1.el6.x86_64) with as minimal downtime as possible, this is an important live databas for a lot of customers (one of our billing backends).

This is what I have been testing:

- Stopping database, pgsql_start_backup() and using rsync on the data folder which corrupts the data
- Dumping database using pg_dump then importing but it takes toooooo much time to import
- I was looking into pg_basebackup and running that over the network but since this feature was introduced in 9.1 I don't have it

What I think could be possible solutions but I don't know if they are possible:

- Running a third party software like Bucardo on the new server and configure it as a slave so that it can start replicating the live server and that way sync all data and then switch, can I run Bucardo on only one server (the new one) and start the replication to the same server? Bucardo replication or native replication?
- Should I try to use pg_upgrade and upgrade my database to 9.1 to get pg_basebackup? However this could introduce a second issue since our third party application specificly installs postgresql-server-9.0.13-5.1.el6.x86_64

Do you have any recommendations how I would move this database to a new server on a different architecture with as minimal downtime as possible (preferably replication until it catches up) with a very big database of 135 GB raw data? (About 60-80 GB data when dumped and compressed with gzip).

Thankful for any help.
Best regards

Comment: You have tried simply copying the entire data directory as-is? You do mention something about the data directory but in combination with pgsql_start_backup() which doesn't ring a bell (google only gives this question as the single result). I'd first rsync the entire directory, then shutdown postgresql and rsync again (which shouldn't take that much time). I've done this often with MySQL, but perhaps postgresql doesn't have architecture-independent data storage. Otherwise my personal choice would be Slony to replicate the DB.

Comment: As you are switching between two architectures (32 -> 64bit), you can not just copy the data directory and I think `pg_basebackup` will also not work in that case because it also "just" does a binary copy.

Comment: Yeah I think is the issues I have been experiencing, if I want to run 32 bit on a new machine I must go back to a new RHEL 4 or CentOS 4 installation which is not possible. Would my best bet be some kind of replication of the data or will I simply have to put out with using `pg_dump` and then import from the dump? This will take hours/days to import so I really want a replication solution, preferably where I don't have to install any additional software on the live server.

Comment: Setting up a trigger based replication (which is your only choice) _will_ need new "software" on the live server - albeit "only" SQL code. As you are upgrading to a also somewhat outdated version you can make use of parallel `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` either. You could try to _pipe_ the output of a `pg_dump` directly into a psql connected to the target server. That should be a bit quicker than dumping to a file and restoring the file.

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name stated, you cannot do this with 'normal' replication.  Setting up and testing a trigger-based logical replication would take possibly much longer than a dump-and-restore, and you still have to move the untouched data somehow (combining these two approaches, for example).  On an other hand, basically all systems need some maintenance windows (for OS upgrades, for example), I'd try no negotiate one.

Comment: I have done a lot of research today and it seems my only option is to take it down for maintenance and try to migrate it manually by dumping and importing. We have a table containing a lot of useless data which we can drop and decrease the size of the database a little, however we are also low on diskspace on this server (around ~15 GB free). Would this cause an issue when using `VACUUM` in PostgreSQL? Does `VACUUM` require a larger amount of free diskspace? I guess my best bet would be to have a maintenance where I decrease the size of the database and then another one for the migration.